Export AlphaFold Server file and visualize on PyMol
I am currently working with AlphaFold Server, which is Google DeepMind's public access release of AlphaFold3, a model for biomolecule structure prediction.
I am using it in order to predict protein-protein interactions and I get satisfactory results. However, the Server is limited in its data visualization abilities. For example, I can pan around in the 3D predicted structure, however I cannot zoom in without losing image quality or modify the colors of the proteins (which they had done in their publication in Nature and which you can do in AlphaFold2 or ColabFold).
I believe there is a place where I can export the atomic coordinates and import the files in PyMOL, however I cannot manage to do it. Would anyone more experienced in structural biology and prediction via AlphaFold be able to help me?
I hope this is the right StackExchange to ask this question, hope I have been descriptive enough; and thank you in advance!

When you hit "Download", you get a zip file containing, among other things, atomic coordinates for the five generated models in cif format which can be read in PyMol, Chimera or another program.
